# How to create an Array Formula with AND

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am facing here an issue that in my workbook. I am using `IF(AND())` in a formula to find the range between two values. As my sheet is large, I have to drag the equation from top to bottom, and there is a chance someone may accidentally erase the formula.

Can you help me to make an array formula so that I can lock that top cell? I hope this will make my sheet little faster. I have a sample sheet here in which I can drag the "If & And" formula up to B8.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Wy7ilXvSv7eY27kZpuiIax6XRKbZKs1bUS5pzgtOOkM/edit#gid=0

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that `AND` doesn't like to play nice with ranges. Luckily, you can use arithmetic operators to work around this:

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(A3:A="","",
  IF((A3:A>=0)*(A3:A<=10),5,
  IF((A3:A>=11)*(A3:A<=19),4,
  IF((A3:A>=20)*(A3:A<=39),3,
  IF((A3:A>=40)*(A3:A<=59),2,
  IF((A3:A>=60)*(A3:A<=79),1,
  IF((A3:A>=80)*(A3:A<=99),0,
  ""))))))
))
```

Simple rules:

- `AND` -> Multiplication
- `OR` -> Addition

Just make sure you wrap comparisons in parens, or the Order of Operations will cause it to fail.

Of course, you can always use some kind of step function formula to get what you want if there's a nice pattern to the intervals, like here.

Answer (score 0):

I would tend to use Vlookup for these where the lookup range is either on another sheet:

```
=ArrayFormula(if(A3:A="","",vlookup(A3:A,Lookup!A1:B10,2)))
```

or in the formula itself:

```
=ArrayFormula(if(A3:A="","",vlookup(A3:A,{0,5;11,4;20,3;40,2;60,1;80,0;100,"***"},2)))
```

[image]

This is the Lookup sheet:

[image]